# suspending a 36x26 solar panel on a single 4x4x12 post (9' above ground 3 feet into the ground)?

Tags: wood, structural, construction, post, solar

I'd like to suspend a 36x26x1 aluminum solar panel 9 feet above ground on a SINGLE 12' 4x4 timber with some 2x4s at the top. I'm in central Florida.

Will it be too top heavy? wind issues?

it's a used panel that cost me $75. Not looking to invest a lot of money or time in this or especially take up any more real estate on the ground than i need to.

[image]

Comment: No wind issues in a location that gets hurricanes. Get your local requirements you might find they are fairly tough if it can be seen.

Comment: There may be local requirements but in my location there is not, the panel mounting system must be signed by a licensed engineer for a specified condition.  In my location in Central Indiana, that is 90 mph wind load with 2' of snow.  I doubt your location has the snow requirement but a 90+ mph wind load would not surprise me.  I am 100% sure that your 4x4 post will not be legal and will be a major hazard.

Comment: Wind will rock the panel, and over time, the mounting hardware will fail...IMHO.

Comment: it could be much improved in terms of stability and safety by trying down the corners to the base of the post with steel cable. Like radio mast towers, but with an inverted pyramid; you still get the triangle strength... The cables will prevent a blown-off panel from killing some kid.